# Eclipse keppler - can't create new instance server of Glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

i can't create new instance server of glassfish

because the next button is disabled and finish button is disabled

eclipse details

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
```

i try to use glassfish with jdk version 1.8.0_05 (64 bit)

also with jdk 1.7.0_51 (32 bit) but also can't create new glassfish server

(because the next button is disabled and finish button is also disabled)

screenshot
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dym4nd&s=8

how to fix it?

**EDIT**

but everything work fine if i create new Tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

Is glassfish3 disabled too? Try to set $JAVA_HOME or add .../bin/java to your $PATH variable. It seems like eclipse can't find appropriate application for glassfish.